# Get bigger picture from facebook links in feed

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I am parsing a facebook feed from a page and i get the pics from the feed from data.picture; if there is a picture link in the feed

This is how i get the data
    function getFeeds(Token)
{

```
var row;
var tableData = [];
var json, data, name, picture, description, likes;

Ti.Facebook.requestWithGraphPath(Titanium.App.Properties.getString("pageID") +'/feed', {access_token: Token}, 'GET', function(e){
    if (e.success) {
        json = JSON.parse(e.result);
        for (i = 0; i < json.data.length; i++) {
        if (json.data[i].message) {
                    row = addRow(json.data[i]); 
                    tableData.push(row); 
                    }
            //  }

       } activityScreen.hide();
        table.setData(tableData);
    } else {
        if (e.error) {
            //alert(e.error);
        } else {
            alert("#serverfail...");
        }
    }
});
}
```

The picture i get is WAY to small.

How can i get a bigger pic?

Thanx

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In order to get bigger picture from the page feed post, first you need to check the type of the feed, if the type equals to photo then you can find extra "object id" in the return result. So using this object id if you send another graph api call. In the return result you will have field called "images". Under images you will have multiple size images From there you can choose the size you want. The default value in the "picture" field is the thumbnail size picture, thats why your picture size is smal. ( [In the fb page, checkout the example link](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/page/) )

```
https://graph.facebook.com/feed ===>

 "picture": "https://fbexternal-a.akamaihd.net/safe_image.php?d=AQB3Wv9mtyMdfNfw&w=90&h=90&url=https%3A%2F%2Fgeneralassemb.ly%2Fassets%2Fstatic%2FWin-A-Trip-To-SF-94fb4a6d732c86534f23e9a9ec2c2d4d.jpg", 
  "link": "https://generalassemb.ly/win/trip-to-sf", 
  "name": "Break Into the Big Leagues", 
  "type": "link",
```

---

```
"type": "photo", 
      "status_type": "added_photos", 
      "object_id": "10151322059288553",
```

if you use this "object_id"

```
    https://graph.facebook.com/10151322059288553

 "height": 300, 
  "width": 720, 
  "images": [
    {
      "height": 853, 
      "width": 2048, 
      "source": "https://fbcdn-sphotos-b-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-prn1/s2048x2048/16985_10151322059288553_286780821_n.jpg"
    }, 
    {
      "height": 392, 
      "width": 940, 
      "source": "https://fbcdn-sphotos-b-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-prn1/16985_10151322059288553_286780821_n.jpg"
    },
```

Comment: To my knowledge, this is the only way to get the larger picture. You have to do another graph request which is unfortunate.

Comment: trying to use this myself. Found the object_id but when i request it i get Unsupported get request. Link - https://graph.facebook.com/10153328434075078 any help appreciated as really struggling with using the facebook api.

Answer (score 6):

If you don't want to make a second graph request you can just replace the s at the end of the picture URL with an n.

So http://photos-h.ak.fbcdn.net/hphotos-ak-ash3/12345_12345_12345_s.jpg becomes So http://photos-h.ak.fbcdn.net/hphotos-ak-ash3/12345_12345_12345_n.jpg

Comment: This still works as of today. However I haven't found a way to resize urls in format `http://external.ak.fbcdn.net/safe_image.php?d=AQAsyWsDk3pqGiqK&w=130&h=130&url=http%3A%2F%2Fi1.ytimg.com%2Fvi%2FurBJNHelfWY%2Fmaxresdefault.jpg`, obvious w and h cannot be modified.

Answer (score 4):

You can't change the size of the photo returned by the safe_image.php links as far as I'm aware, so if the link is not to a Facebook Object, the best you can do is extract the 'url' query string variable from the link, urldecode it and grab the original picture.

e.g. if your URL (from the 'picture' property of a post) was

```
https://fbexternal-a.akamaihd.net/safe_image.php?d=AQBMV0YW8BCmCBMB&w=154&h=154&url=https%3A%2F%2Ffbstatic-a.akamaihd.net%2Frsrc.php%2Fv2%2Fy6%2Fr%2FYQEGe6GxI_M.png
```

and stored in the variable `url`, then this should return the URL of the full size image:

```
decodeURIComponent(url.match(/(url=)(.+)$/)[2]);
```